# Android Studio: Set reminder for specific date and time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm a student at high school who's dramatically underestimated how difficult it would be to wrap my head around android studio. After 3 months of struggling I've managed to pound out most of the issues, but I still have one major thing I need to complete:

I need to set a reminder for a user defined date and time that will appear as a notification or something. I've tried every tutorial out there but I don't really know what I'm doing. At this point, I just need someone to walk me through it step by step because I'm at my wits end and regretting ever trying to take this project on.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
final static int req1=1;
public String a = "0"; // initialize this globally at the top of your class.

private void setAlarm(Calendar target){   
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), req1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, target.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    a ="1";
}
```

For calling this method:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2016, 0, 23, 18, 5, 0);
setAlarm(cal);
if(a.equals("0")
{
  // do whatever you want to do.  
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your reply. It's good to get some help! Just three questions: req1 shows up as an error, sorry if this is a dumb question, but what is is supposed to be? AlarmReciever also is an error, was I supposed to have done something else with it? Lastly, the setText shows up as an error.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally hit send without finishing the comment. I edited the comment with some questions

Comment: I have edited my answer pls check. Instead of AlarmReceiver replace with your class name.

Comment: Awesome you've been so helpful thanks, sorry for being a bother. One last thing: For the cal.set, what is the format for the time/date? I assume it's something like year/month/day/hour/minute/second? Is the hour in 24 hour time, or how is it done thanks.

Comment: This code will set the alarm/reminder to 23 January, 2016, 18:05:00.

Comment: Awesome it seems to be working fine now. I know this is getting old, but one last thing: How do I make the app do something when the alarm triggers?

Comment: `public String a = "0";` initialize this globally. And inside setAlarm method at the last line make a = "1"; and using this flag do what you want after alarm strikes. Pls see my edited answer.

Comment: You can even compare the system date and time and alarm set date and time. If they match then that is where the alarm will be triggered and you can do your functions there.